# Remove silicone stain from ceiling

Tags: ceiling, stain, silicone, stain-removal

I made a mistake and ended up with a very light coat of cured silicone spread in the ceiling. So looking at an angle, this ceiling area is shining.

I can't just scrap it off because it very thin and feels like stuck in the porous painted ceiling.

What would be the best way to fix this:

- painting over it is an option? maybe not, the new paint might not adhere to silicone.
- using a sandpaper to try to scrap?
- using vinegar (I heard it helps loose the cured silicone).
- using alcohol?

It's a small area so ideally I don't want to buy a whole bottle of solvent. However if it's the only solution I'd do it, I just don't know which solvent to use. Will it be necessary to repaint later?

Thanks!

Comment: How much area of silicone do you have?  1 sqft?  5 sqft?

Comment: @JPhi1618 around 7 x 7 inches of the ceiling area is now stained and shining because of this thin silicone coat mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that painting over the silicone is out just because it's a different surface to begin with.  Assuming you had a paint that would stick to it long-term, the paint in that spot will always have a different sheen.

Removal is the best option, and it may be a matter of trying options to see what will work best and damage the ceiling the least.  Chemicals that soften the silicone can make the job easier, but I think they would seep into the drywall and create similar issues for painting.

You say you are worried about scraping, but I think it may be a better option even if it means patching the area with spackling or similar if you gouge the drywall.  I would try very rough sand paper (below 80 grit, then maybe a brass wire brush, then a sharp scraper.

I admit that I have never tried to remove exactly what you are dealing with, so take this as one man's opinion.

Comment: I scrapped and it removed the shining effect. However when looking at an angle, you can see it looks different than the rest, because this area is now smooth (sanded) compared to the natural rough area around. Repainting would maybe help? Or need to put some compound? If you have an idea, I appreciate. Thanks!

Comment: Yea, that area will need some texture touch up.  How you do that will depend on the texture of the ceiling.  You can post a new question with pictures of the ceiling for help on that, but texture touch up kits are common items at home stores.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much nothing sticks to silicone.  Thus you will have to abrade it off with rough sandpaper.  If you use a sander its easier, try not to sand past the silicone and through the ceiling paint/texture and past the drywall paper to bare gypsum.  If you do, no huge biggie just skim a little drywall joint compound on...but it may look worse than the shine.